# Why does Heroku has to install so many modules every time?

Tags: git, heroku, push

I am developing an app in Django and I am deploying it on Heroku.

Why does, with each push, Heroku has to install all these modules?

I know there is a way to prevent it from doing it all the times, because when I was deploying another app I somehow disabled it, but I can't remember how to do it.

```
remote:        Collecting backcall==0.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 1)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/71/c8ca4f5bb1e08401b916c68003acf0a0655df935d74d93bf3f3364b310e0/backcall-0.1.0.tar.gz 
remote:        Collecting backports.csv==1.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 2)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/26/a6bd68f13e0f38fbb643d6e497fc3462be83a0b6c4d43425c78bb51a7291/backports.csv-1.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting certifi==2019.9.11 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 3)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/b0/8146a4f8dd402f60744fa380bc73ca47303cccf8b9190fd16a827281eac2/certifi-2019.9.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB) 
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 4)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB) 
remote:        Collecting chart-studio==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 5)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/3f/d2f3f506ba1aaf109f549f8b01d1483cd3e324c5ebe6b206acee66efdf46/chart_studio-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (76kB) 
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 6)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/a6/728666f39bfff1719fc94c481890b2106837da9318031f71a8424b662e12/colorama-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting colorlover==0.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 7)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/53/f696e4480b1d1de3b1523991dea71cf417c8b19fe70c704da164f3f90972/colorlover-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting decorator==4.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 8)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8f/b7/f329cfdc75f3d28d12c65980e4469e2fa373f1953f5df6e370e84ea2e875/decorator-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting defusedxml==0.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 9)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/74/9b387472866358ebc08732de3da6dc48e44b0aacd2ddaa5cb85ab7e986a2/defusedxml-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting diff-match-patch==20181111 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 10)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/2a/5ba07def0e9107d935aba62cf632afbd0f7c723a98af47ccbcab753d2452/diff-match-patch-20181111.tar.gz (58kB) 
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 11)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting Django==2.2.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 12)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/4b/743d5008fc7432c714d753e1fc7ee56c6a776dc566cc6cfb4136d46cdcbb/Django-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.4MB) 
remote:        Collecting django-filter==2.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 13)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/c9/acc63b687002afae8b5137afd6230d88c99411aa2daedf07fed3f0913516/django_filter-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (69kB) 
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 14)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/af/5475a876c5addd5a3494db47d9f7be93cc14d3a7603542b194572791b6c6/django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting django-import-export==1.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 15)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/7a/ddd9aef718243504e7715bda9bb5a100cfc353be37dc819d9914a7073cba/django_import_export-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75kB) 
remote:        Collecting django-staticfiles-moment==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 16)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ad/a1/3e5b529cb67de4d66f4a68510236ed6d8bb0e23fbeeb5ef56d57a40e601e/django-staticfiles-moment-2.0.0.tar.gz (72kB) 
remote:        Collecting et-xmlfile==1.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 17)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/28/a99c42aea746e18382ad9fb36f64c1c1f04216f41797f2f0fa567da11388/et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz 
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 18)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB) 
remote:        Collecting idna==2.8 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 19)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/2c/cd551d81dbe15200be1cf41cd03869a46fe7226e7450af7a6545bfc474c9/idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB) 
remote:        Collecting ipython==7.9.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 20)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/2e/59cdacea6476a4c21b7c090a91250ffbcd085900f5eb9f4e4d68dd2ee4e3/ipython-7.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (775kB) 
remote:        Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 21)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fa/bc/9bd3b5c2b4774d5f33b2d544f1460be9df7df2fe42f352135381c347c69a/ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting jdcal==1.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 22)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/da/572cbc0bc582390480bbd7c4e93d14dc46079778ed915b505dc494b37c57/jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting jedi==0.15.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 23)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/54/da994f359e4e7da4776a200e76dbc85ba5fc319eefc22e33d55296d95a1d/jedi-0.15.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.0MB) 
remote:        Collecting mysql-connector-python==8.0.16 (from
-r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 24)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f5/55dd794bb70a9b73510454ac3fb57c27450d70eaf5811f4fb618b80bcace/mysql_connector_python-8.0.16-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.0MB) 
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.17.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 25)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/e6/c3fdc53aed9fa19d6ff3abf97dfad768ae3afce1b7431f7500000816bda5/numpy-1.17.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.4MB) 
remote:        Collecting odfpy==1.4.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 26)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/85/7d/8f6d1f2a4683be362b101c00232b4c3839e4e4a90e0945d8d43ec6aa671d/odfpy-1.4.0.tar.gz (715kB) 
remote:        Collecting openpyxl==3.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 27)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/af/88ff9eef0b8f665aee1111ac6cede5ad12190c5bd726242bd2b26fc21b32/openpyxl-3.0.0.tar.gz (172kB) 
remote:        Collecting pandas==0.25.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 28)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/9b/52e228545d14f14bb2a1622e225f38463c8726645165e1cb7dde95bfe6d4/pandas-0.25.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.5MB) 
remote:        Collecting parso==0.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 29)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a3/bd/bf4e5bd01d79906e5b945a7af033154da49fd2b0d5b5c705a21330323305/parso-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (95kB) 
remote:        Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 30)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/41/220f49aaea88bc6fa6cba8d05ecf24676326156c23b991e80b3f2fc24c77/pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting playsound==1.2.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 31)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/16/10d897b0a83fb4b05b03a63d7a2667ab75f857f67f7062fd447dd3f49bf7/playsound-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting plotly==4.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 32)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/67/eb2b2be7a63a66548abea92447fc04d9abf363520f1af6145c5f033cd1b3/plotly-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB) 
remote:        Collecting prompt-toolkit==2.0.10 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 33)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/61/2dfea88583d5454e3a64f9308a686071d58d59a55db638268a6413e1eb6d/prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (340kB) 
remote:        Collecting protobuf==3.8.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 34)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/fb/29de8d08967f0cce1bb10b39846d836b0f3bf6776ddc36aed7c73498ca7e/protobuf-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2MB) 
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.8.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 35)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz (368kB) 
remote:        Collecting Pygments==2.4.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 36)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/73/1dfa428150e3ccb0fa3e68db406e5be48698f2a979ccbcec795f28f44048/Pygments-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (883kB) 
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 37)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (226kB) 
remote:        Collecting python-decouple==3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 38)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/99/ddfbb6362af4ee239a012716b1371aa6d316ff1b9db705bfb182fbc4780f/python-decouple-3.1.tar.gz 
remote:        Collecting pytz==2019.1 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 39)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3d/73/fe30c2daaaa0713420d0382b16fbb761409f532c56bdcc514bf7b6262bb6/pytz-2019.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510kB) 
remote:        Collecting PyYAML==5.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 40)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e3/e8/b3212641ee2718d556df0f23f78de8303f068fe29cdaa7a91018849582fe/PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265kB) 
remote:        Collecting requests==2.22.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 41)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/bd/23c926cd341ea6b7dd0b2a00aba99ae0f828be89d72b2190f27c11d4b7fb/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57kB) 
remote:        Collecting retrying==1.3.3 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 42)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/ef/beae4b4ef80902f22e3af073397f079c96969c69b2c7d52a57ea9ae61c9d/retrying-1.3.3.tar.gz 
remote:        Collecting six==1.12.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 43)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting sqlparse==0.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 44)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/53/900f7d2a54557c6a37886585a91336520e5539e3ae2423ff1102daf4f3a7/sqlparse-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting tablib==0.13.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 45)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/c7/cb74031b330cd94f3580926dc707d148b4ba9138449fc9f433cb79e640d8/tablib-0.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (75kB) 
remote:        Collecting traitlets==4.3.3 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 46)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/ab/872a23e29cec3cf2594af7e857f18b687ad21039c1f9b922fac5b9b142d5/traitlets-4.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75kB) 
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.25.7 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 47)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/40/a9837291310ee1ccc242ceb6ebfd9eb21539649f193a7c8c86ba15b98539/urllib3-1.25.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125kB) 
remote:        Collecting virtualenv==16.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 48)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/ee/8375c01412abe6ff462ec80970e6bb1c4308724d4366d7519627c98691ab/virtualenv-16.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.0MB) 
remote:        Collecting wcwidth==0.1.7 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 49)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9f/526a6947247599b084ee5232e4f9190a38f398d7300d866af3ab571a5bfe/wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==4.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 50)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/2a/b51377ab9826f0551da19951257d2434f46329cd6cfdf9592ea9ca5f6034/whitenoise-4.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Collecting xlrd==1.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 51)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/16/63576a1a001752e34bf8ea62e367997530dc553b689356b9879339cf45a4/xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103kB) 
remote:        Collecting xlwt==1.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 52)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/48/def306413b25c3d01753603b1a222a011b8621aed27cd7f89cbc27e6b0f4/xlwt-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (99kB) 
remote:        Collecting pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" (from ipython==7.9.0->-r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 20)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/7b/88dbb785881c28a102619d46423cb853b46dbccc70d3ac362d99773a78ce/pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59kB) 
remote:        Collecting ptyprocess>=0.5 (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython==7.9.0->-r /tmp/build_766c0cb2a662d94bf7b1c2a8ad2a3cd4/requirements.txt (line 20)) 
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/29/605c2cc68a9992d18dada28206eeada56ea4bd07a239669da41674648b6f/ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
remote:        Installing collected packages: backcall, backports.csv, certifi, chardet, urllib3, idna, requests, six, retrying, plotly, chart-studio, colorama, colorlover, decorator, defusedxml, diff-match-patch, dj-database-url, pytz, sqlparse, Django, django-filter, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, PyYAML, xlwt, xlrd, jdcal, et-xmlfile, openpyxl, odfpy, tablib, django-import-export, django-staticfiles-moment, gunicorn, Pygments, ipython-genutils, traitlets, pickleshare, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, parso, jedi, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython, protobuf, mysql-connector-python, numpy, python-dateutil, pandas, playsound, python-decouple, virtualenv 
remote:          Running setup.py install for backcall: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for backcall: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for retrying: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for retrying: finished with status 'done' 
remote:     Running setup.py install for diff-match-patch: started 
remote:         Running setup.py install for diff-match-patch: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for PyYAML: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for PyYAML: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for et-xmlfile: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for et-xmlfile: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for openpyxl: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for openpyxl: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for odfpy: started 
remote:   Running setup.py install for odfpy: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for django-staticfiles-moment: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for django-staticfiles-moment: finished with status 'done' 
remote:          Running setup.py install for python-decouple: started 
remote:            Running setup.py install for python-decouple: finished with status 'done' 
remote:        Successfully installed Django-2.2.2 PyYAML-5.1.2 Pygments-2.4.2 backcall-0.1.0 backports.csv-1.0.7 certifi-2019.9.11 chardet-3.0.4 chart-studio-1.0.0 colorama-0.4.1 colorlover-0.3.0 decorator-4.4.1 defusedxml-0.6.0 diff-match-patch-20181111 dj-database-url-0.5.0 django-filter-2.2.0 django-heroku-0.3.1 django-import-export-1.2.0 django-staticfiles-moment-2.0.0 et-xmlfile-1.0.1 gunicorn-19.9.0 idna-2.8 ipython-7.9.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jdcal-1.4.1 jedi-0.15.1 mysql-connector-python-8.0.16 numpy-1.17.2 odfpy-1.4.0 openpyxl-3.0.0 pandas-0.25.1 parso-0.5.1 pexpect-4.8.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 playsound-1.2.2 plotly-4.3.0 prompt-toolkit-2.0.10 protobuf-3.8.0 psycopg2-2.8.2 ptyprocess-0.6.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 python-decouple-3.1 pytz-2019.1 requests-2.22.0 retrying-1.3.3 six-1.12.0 sqlparse-0.3.0 tablib-0.13.0 traitlets-4.3.3 urllib3-1.25.7 virtualenv-16.6.0 wcwidth-0.1.7 whitenoise-4.1.2 xlrd-1.2.0 xlwt-1.3.0
```

Comment: Which buildpack do you use?

Comment: heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it:

One must do all the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60910434/pyton-application-cant-deploy-to-heroku/61193538#61193538), especially:

> In your project main folder add a folder named staticfiles, and inside
> this folder add a file named **init**.py and leave it blank.
>
> Then in your settings.py add:
>
> ```
> STATICSTORAGE = "Whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
> ```
>
> Again in settings.py, inside `MIDDLEWARE`, add:
>
> ```
> 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
> ```

then run from command prompt

> ```
> pip freeze>requirements.txt
> pip install whitenoise
> heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
> ```

which collects the staticfiles in a remote folder, in heroku app directory.