# Python application cant deploy to Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I find this error whiledeploying it to heroku.

> cp: cannot create regular file
> '/app/tmp/cache/.heroku/requirements.txt': No such file or directory

Project's `procfile`:

```
web: python app.py
```

project's `runtime.txt`:

```
python-3.7.6
```

project's `requirements.txt`:

```
    APScheduler==3.6.3
    certifi==2019.11.28
    Click==7.0
    colorhash==1.0.2
    configparser==4.0.2
    cycler==0.10.0
    Flask==1.1.1
    Flask-Cors==3.0.8
    gunicorn==20.0.4
    itsdangerous==1.1.0
    Jinja2==2.11.0
    kiwisolver==1.1.0
    kneed==0.5.3
    MarkupSafe==1.1.1
    numpy==1.18.1
    psutil==5.7.0
    pyparsing==2.4.6
    python-dateutil==2.8.1
    six==1.14.0
    SQLAlchemy==1.3.13
    tzlocal==2.0.0
    Werkzeug==0.16.1
    wincertstore==0.2
    chardet==3.0.4
    decorator==4.4.1
    entrypoints==0.3
    idna==2.8
    jsonschema==3.2.0
    matplotlib==3.1.3
    mccabe==0.6.1
    pandas==1.0.1
    pytz==2019.3
    pyzmq==18.1.1
    requests==2.22.0
    soupsieve==1.9.5
    urllib3==1.25.8
    webencodings==0.5.1
    widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
```

Anyone experienced this ? please guide me if so.

Comment: After somehow it deployed to heroku but when I ran the application it comes out in logs Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch. Dont know how to deal with that, please help

Comment: do see my answer let me know if it helps.

Comment: same error on my side.i try to fix it last day but i cannot do so.search on internet but no solve this

Comment: I have the same problem as in the original question

Answer (score 0):

It would have been great if you showed the script that you are trying to run. Without that, I am assuming the error may be related to the wrong configuration in procfile.

Try replacing `web` with `worker` in your Procfile.

If you have a "web" process type in your Procfile, the dyno running that process must bind to its assigned $PORT within 60 seconds (by default), in order to be able to respond to incoming web requests over http/s. If it doesn't, Heroku takes down the dyno as explained [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case anyway this error can happen if you make a mistake when specifying which file to start in the Procfile.

For example in your case if instead of app.py your filename is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

on your cmd prompt:

```
pip install gunicorn
pip install whitenoise
pip freeze>requirements.txt
```

In your project main folder add a file named `Procfile` (no extention), and inside this file type:

```
web: gunicorn your_project_(main_folder)_name.wsgi
```

**Note:** In your procfile you typed `app.py`, but it should rather be `my_project.wsgi`. Maybe this is sufficient to solve your problem.

In your project main folder add a folder named `staticfiles`, and inside this folder add a file named `__init__.py` and leave it blank.

Then in your settings.py add:

```
STATICSTORAGE = "Whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

Again in settings.py, inside `MIDDLEWARE`, add:

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

Finally on your cmd prompt:

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever you want"
git push heroku master
```

If I am correct, the first time you will push your code to Heroku, it will tell again

> cannot create regular file '/app/tmp/cache/.heroku/requirements.txt':
> No such file or directory

but then it will collect all the static files and then succeed in deploying.

From next time, it will no more print out all the static files collected.

If not, try to run

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```